# What does the range operator (double-dot "..") do when multipied?

Tags: rust, range, operator-precedence

I recently came across this expression in some [code written by GUILLAUME ENDIGNOUX](https://gendignoux.com/blog/2021/04/01/rust-async-streams-futures-part1.html), which produces a vector of 10 numbers:

```
 (10 * i..10 * (i + 1)).collect()
```

Gives: 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429

Here is a working example, where I have replaced the number "10" with "3" to simplify:

```
fn main() {
    let v = get_data(42);
    assert_eq!(v, [126, 127, 128]);
}

fn get_data(i: usize) -> Vec<usize>{
    (3 * i..3 * (i + 1)).collect() // How does this work?
}
```

What is going on here?

Changing the first number to for instance 1,like so:

```
( 1 * i..3 * (i + 1)).collect()
```

I expected the vecor to contain 1 element, but I got all numbers from 42 to 128 (inclusive). I.e. 86 numbers in total.

Comment: It's equivalent to `( (3 * i) .. (3 * (i + 1)) )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `..` operator has fairly low precedence meaning that your multiplication applies before it.

So

```rust
(1 * i..3 * (i + 1)).collect()
```

is equivalent to

```rust
((1 * i)..(3 * (i + 1)).collect()
```

with a value `42` for `i` that gives the range `42..129`, matching what you observe.